# Having trouble with show and hide div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My code: https://jsfiddle.net/Metalnoypi/d7ocf929/#&togetherjs=HD16R9BLLF

I'm currently semi-new to javascript/html/css and I'm having trouble of having the main menu page disappear at the click of the start button, and then having the word Test appear as soon as the menu disappears. Any recommendations would be helpful! Also, if possible could you also explain how it works/?

```
<menu>
<div id="menu">
  <body background="">
<divcenter>
<font color="blue"><font size="5"><center><h2> Realm of Rilthalk </h2></center></font></font>
<font color="magenta"><font size="5"><center><h3>The Origin Story</h3></center></font></font>
</divcenter>
<divbottomleft> <input type="button" id="start" class="hide" value = "Start Game"/> </divbottomleft>
<divbottomright><input type="button" id="quit" value = "Quit"/>
</divbottomright>
</body>
</div>
</menu>
<game>
<div id="game" class="toshow" style="display:none" >
<divcenter><font color="jade"><H1><center> Test </center></H1></font>
</divcenter>
</div>
</game>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".hide").click(function(){
    $(this).parents("menu").hide();
        $("game").parents("game").toggle();    
});
});

</script>
```

My CSS Code is:

```
divcenter {
height: 200px;
width: 400px;
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -100px;
margin-left: -200px;
}

divbottomleft {
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: 75px;
margin-left: -200px;
}

divbottomright{
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: 75px;
margin-left: 130px;
}
```

Comment: while click on start button what you have to do

Comment: I'm trying to make it so that when you hit start the menu disappears, then the game shows up, but the game currently is a place holder of the word Test.

Comment: $(".hide").click(function(){
    $("#menu").hide();
        $("#game").show();    
});

Comment: Hope this will help you a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, though your jQuery just needs some slight modification. It's actually surprisingly simple; all you have to do is hide the menu and show the game itself through the same click function:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hide").click(function() {
    $("#menu").hide();
    $("#game").show();
  });
});
```

```css
divcenter {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: -200px;
}

divbottomleft {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: 75px;
  margin-left: -200px;
}

divbottomright {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: 75px;
  margin-left: 130px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<menu>
  <div id="menu">

    <body background="">
      <divcenter>
        <font color="blue"><font size="5"><center><h2> Realm of Rilthalk </h2></center></font></font>
        <font color="magenta"><font size="5"><center><h3>The Origin Story</h3></center></font></font>
      </divcenter>
      <divbottomleft>
        <input type="button" id="start" class="hide" value="Start Game" /> </divbottomleft>
      <divbottomright>
        <input type="button" id="quit" value="Quit" />
      </divbottomright>
    </body>
  </div>
</menu>
<game>
  <div id="game" class="toshow" style="display:none">
    <divcenter><font color="jade"><H1><center> Test </center></H1></font>
    </divcenter>
  </div>
</game>
```

I've also created a JSFiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2m01asm6/).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: No problem; glad to hear this solution appears to have worked for you. Once you've confirmed this solution solves your problem, please don't forget to mark the solution as correct by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things flowing smoothly :)